# Java: When NOT to use `private`

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

Since it's regarded bad OO practice to have public variables in a class (instead, use getters and setters) then why not use `private` on **all** variables? Why does Java even permit using `public` if it's bad practice?

(This doesn't apply to functions, obviously)

Comment: Regardless of having thrown in my 2 cents with an answer, I don't think this question is answerable with anything but guesses (of which there are many) short of Gosling stopping by to explain himself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `public static final` variable is a good reason for example. Like a constant.

Answer (score 4):

Having a `public` or `private` field is a design decision.  The language itself is supposed to *enable* programmers to make their own design decisions, not *enforce* a design that the developer or team may not necessarily want to implement.

The more flexible the language, the more powerful it is.  It's up to the project manager, the team, or the individual developer to determine the most appropriate way for a field to be accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Access control of variable fields is not the only concern.

Consider *simplicity*. Java has a single default for access control of all types. This is easier to learn than having different access rules for different types.

Consider *usability* for new users. If everything were private by default, new users would be more likely confused about why something could not be accessed.

Finally, note that "getters and setters" are not always the appropriate alternative to public fields. Some fields should not be modified or even accessed outside the class.

**[EDIT]** There's also a *historical* reason behind the choice. The earliest versions of Java, then known as "Oak," **had no private access**. The default, and most-restricted access was package-protected. (Reference: this [2002 Java newsletter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue055.html), citing the [Oak 0.2 manual](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/files/OakSpec0.2.ps).)

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of managing complexity.

A `public` member can be accessed from outside the class, which for practical considerations means "potentially anywhere". If something goes wrong with a `public` field, the culprit can be anywhere, and so in order to track down the bug, you may have to look at quite a lot of code.

A `private` member can only be accessed from inside the same class, so if something goes wrong with that, there is usually only one source file to look at. If you have a million lines of code in your project, but your classes are kept small, this can reduce your bug tracking effort by a lot.

Another advantage is related to the concept of [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29).  Some answers forgot to mention this.

I'd say make everything `private` by default, and then expose only those parts that absolutely have to be `public` (or just use getters and setters). The more you can make `private`, the better.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a good part of the reason is "C++ did it that way". Different languages disagree on this issue, so it's obviously not the only sensible choice. E.g. Python has everything public and trusts you to follow a library's documentation, while Ruby only has private fields.

Answer (score 0):

It's about where you want to *publish* the field.

For `public` fields, you could safely do it for `final` fields, like constants:

```
public static final ...
```

And `final` fields:

```
public final ...
```

like the `length` field in java arrays. Although the convention is to provide a accessor method (a getter) in preference to making a field public.

Use `protected` fields when you want to publish the field to
subclasses.

Use default visibility (ie not specified) when you want to publish the field to other classes in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is good to have this possibility (excluding `static final` constants), because You can use this to solve some problems quickly(instead of defining getters and setters), you just need to be careful here by breaking encapsulation rules.